# Type mismatch when idea calls Scala varargs function in a Kotlin project

Tags: scala, kotlin, intellij-idea, variadic-functions

let's say I have a function foo() in a scala library called

```
 @varargs def foo(first: Kitty, alternatives: Kitty*): Kitty= KittyAdapter {
    import kitty.overlord.Rules._

    (first +: alternatives).map(_.delegate).reduce(_ ~ _)
  }
```

and when I call this function in a kotlin project like this

```
fun bar():Kitty = foo(
scab,
sbab,
blab
)
```

the idea compiles fine but the intellisense shows

> Type mismatch required: Seq < Kitty!>!, found: Kitty!

and the whole piece of code goes red.

Comment: Sounds like [KT-32789](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32789) / [KT-32292](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32292)

Comment: It's gotta be it, KT-32292 is just the kind of mess I'm in, thanks for your info

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, Idea 2019.3.1 and scala plugin 2019.3.23 works fine.